# extract barcode in pdf using c#

Tags: c#, pdf, barcode, rasterizing, pdf-conversion

Is there a way to extract barcode numbers from a pdf document (spanning several pages) in C#.
The pdf document is basically obtained from a scanner.
If possible, I wouldn't like to use any third party library.

Thanks.

Comment: what have you already tried?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: PDF standard is not that simple as you might think, here is a list of PDF software that can save some time http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PDF_software

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your PDF comes from scanner, there is big chance that it contains image only. In other word it use PDF as an container of multiple pages. So, what you need to do is 1) extract the image out of PDF file, 2) load bar code from raster image.

If you only deal with specific scanner, you can read the PDF Specification and and write a small program do the first part. However, my suggestion would be use a good PDF Library to do that, because PDF is a complex format.

For barcode analysis, you should also find a barcode reader program/library.